# Why does ~email return a network path?

Tags: python, macos, bash, terminal

I came across this while trying to use a Python script that used `~Email` to refer to the email column of a csv. When entering just `~email` / `~Email` into a prompt, it returns

```
host is down: /Network/Servers/my.server.domain/Volumes/files/teachers/Group
```

This happens in bash, zsh, iterm, terminal, and on other computers bound to our server. These other computers have no aliases or command line utilities set up. Can someone explain this to me and how I can disable it to be able to use this script?

OS 10.9.5

Comment: What does `echo ~` show on the command line? What's your home directory?

Comment: You have an email user on your system and that is that user's home directory. This is [Tilde Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Tilde-Expansion).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the home directory of an account named `email`. You can avoid this shell home directory-substitution by escaping the `~` (`\~email`) or single-quoting the string (`'~email'`).